# Macos application windows don't show up in the correct space (or even on the correct monitor) when relaunching most applications

Tags: macos

When restarting, open finder windows are able to consistently restore to the spaces they were in before the restart. However, other applications don't seem to be able to do this. Upon restart, or just quitting and then relaunching a specific program, any restored windows seem to just pick a monitor at random and usually go to the first space on that monitor, but occasionally a different one. Is there any way to make this behavior consistent for all applications, or it just a bug that I have to live with?

I am on 10.14.6 (mojave) if it matters, but I think I remember this problem being present on previous OS versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Some apps are incapable of remembering which screen they should be on in a dual-screen setup & will always launch on the primary. Discord  & Apple's own Messages.app & are two, off the top of my head.

For everything else, so long as you don't try to run an app in more than one Space at a time, or use fullscreen, it should work.
Apps will not respect placing across multiple Spaces simultaneously…  & fullscreen respects nothing [yet another reason I never use it].

If you want to fix an app to a Space, move it to that Space first, then in the Dock, right-click > Options > This Desktop. Again, this does not apply to fullscreened apps.